Completing a proof of the inequality $\sqrt{24a+1}+\sqrt{24b+1}+\sqrt{24c+1}\geq 15$, given that $a,b,c\geq 0$ and $ab+bc+ca=a+b+c>0$
Context: The problem is from this website. There are 2 given solutions, but the first seems fairly unintuitive. The second one though is incomplete, as the author apparently found a flaw but never fixed it. I've tried completing the proof, but no luck.
Here is the second partial solution (in short):

The well known inequality $ab+bc+ca\leq \frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)^2,$ along with the given condition implies that $
3\leq a+b+c$. Applying AM-GM to the LHS of the desired inequality gives
$$
LHS \geq 3[(24a+1)(24b+1)(24c+1)]^{\frac{1}{6}}
$$
so it suffices to prove that this new expression is greater than $15$. Expanding, we have
$$
3[(24a+1)(24b+1)(24c+1)]^{\frac{1}{6}}\geq 15  \iff  24^3abc+24\cdot 25(a+b+c)\geq 5^6-1=15624
$$
If $abc\geq 1$, then $24^3abc+24\cdot 25(a+b+c) \geq 24^3\cdot 1+24\cdot 25(3) =15624$, as desired. The case where $abc=0$ is similar.

It is the case when $0<abc<1$ that is missing from the solutions, and I'm finding it difficult to prove.
I've tried using other inequalities that give relations between $abc, a+b+c, ab+bc+ca$ (such as equivalent forms of Schur's inequality), but I've not made any progress.

Here is a proof which relies on lower bounds for the radicals. Though lengthy, it should be clear to read since the outline follows  these lines:

Establish a method for lower bounds for the radicals. Use this with two equality conditions, which greatly restricts the range of $\sum a$ which has to be investigated.
Expand this method for three equality conditions, and use Schur's inequality as already quoted in @River Li's answer.
At various instances, the equality $ab+bc+ca=a+b+c$ given in the question is used.

First note that equality is obtained for $(a,b,c) = (1,1,1)$ and $(a,b,c) = (0,2,2)$ and permutations.
Part 1. Looking at the second case, we seek a lower bound for the radicals with equality at  $a=0$ and $a=2$.  To get this, require that
$$
(p + q a)^2 (24 a +1) - (p + r a)^2 - 24 q^2 a (a-2)^2 = 0 \tag{1}
$$
Using the same parameter $p$ in the quadratic terms assures that the equation holds for $a=0$. The choice of $24 q^2$ derives from the leading $a^3$-term.
Since $a\ge 0$, the equation (1) will  guarantee that $
(p + q a)^2 (24 a +1) \ge (p + r a)^2$.
Expanding in $a$ gives the equations
$$
24 p^2 + 2 p q - 2 p r - 96 q^2 = 0 \quad ; \\ 
48 p q + 97 q^2 - r^2 = 0 \quad .
$$
Homogeneity allows for "nice" (i.e. integer) solutions, they are $p= 8; q = 3 ; r = 45$.
Hence we have that
$$
\sqrt{24a +1 } \geq \frac{8 + 45 a}{8 + 3a }$$
with equality for $a =0$ and $a=2$.
Using this inequality for all radicals, it would suffice to show that
$$
\frac{8 + 45 a}{8 + 3a }
 + \frac{8 + 45 b}{8 + 3b }
 + \frac{8 + 45 c}{8 + 3c } - 15 \ge 0 \tag{2}$$
Full expansion gives
$$
810 a b c + 1152 \sum a b + 384 \sum a  - 6144 \ge 0 
$$
Since by the task, the two sums are equal, we obtain $135 a b c + 256 (\sum a - 4) \ge 0 \tag{3} .$ This is the case for $\sum a \ge  4$. So what remains is the case $abc \le 1$ ;  $3\le \sum a \le 4$. In this case, we can use Schur's inequality and  the task's sum condition to get  $a b c \ge \frac{4(\sum a)^2 - (\sum a)^3}{9}$. Inserting into (3) gives
$60(\sum a)^2 - 15(\sum a)^3 + 256 (\sum a - 4) \ge 0 \tag{4}$ which does not hold. This was expected, since we constructed the radical inequality only for equality conditions at  $a=0$ and $a=2$, missing out $a=1$.
Part 2. To get the final solution, regard the case $abc \le 1$ ;  $3\le \sum a \le 4$.
Note that the conditions on  $\sum a $ can be held very tight which will be useful later. From the task, we only had $13824 abc+ 600 \sum a \ge 15624$ which technically would have required to inspect a range of $3 \le \sum a \le 26.04$ which is not helpful.
Now construct a radical inequality with equality conditions at  $a=0$ and $a=1$ and $a=2$. To do so, expand the ansatz above to
$$
(p + q a + ra^2)^2 (24 a +1) - (p + s a + ta^2)^2 - 24 r^2 a (a-1)^2 (a-2)^2 = 0 \tag{5}
$$
Performing the same steps as above, we obtain
$$
\sqrt{24a +1 } \geq \frac{4 + 46 a + 25a^2}{4 + 10 a  + a^2}$$
with equality for $a =0$ and $a=1$ and $a=2$. Inserting this into the inequality as in (2), and fully expanding, we obtain
$$
60 a^2 b^2 c ^2 + 396 \sum a^2b^2c + 144 \sum a^2 b^2 + 1920 \sum a^2 b c + 624 \sum a^2(b+c) + 192 \sum a^2 - 1200 a b c - 1920 \sum ab - 1344 \sum a - 768 > 0 \tag{6} $$
Now some auxiliary equations are needed which can be derived from the task's sum condition. Let $P = a b c $ and $S = \sum a = \sum a b$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
& \sum a^2 = S^2 - 2 S \\
& \sum a^2(b+c) = S^2 - 3 P \\
& \sum a^2 b c = P \, S \\
& \sum a^2 b^2 = S^2 - 2 P \, S \\
& \sum a^2 b^2 c = P \, S \\
\end{align}
$$
Plugging this into (6) gives
$$
5 P^2 + P (169 S - 256) + 80 S^2 - 304 S - 64 \ge 0
$$
Since $S = \sum a \ge 3$ we can bound $P$ by Schur's inequality as above, $ P \ge \frac{4S^2 - S^3}{9}$ and it is enough to show
$$
5 (\frac{4S^2 - S^3}{9})^2 + \frac{4S^2 - S^3}{9} (169 S - 256) + 80 S^2 - 304 S - 64 \ge 0
$$
or, expanded,
$$
5 S^6 - 40 S^5 - 1441 S^4 + 8388 S^3 - 2736 S^2 - 24624 S - 5184 \ge 0
$$
for $3 \le S \le 4$. Indeed, equality holds for $S = 3$ and $S=4$ so we can divide the polynomial by $(S-3)(4-S)$, giving
$
432 + 2304 S + 1536 S^2 + 5 S^3 - 5 S^4 \ge 0
$, or, with $S = 3 + T$, $-5 T^4 - 55 T^3 + 1311 T^2 + 11115 T + 20898 \ge 0$, which is certainly true for $0 \le T \le 1$. This completes the proof. $\qquad \square$

Very interesting!

Some thoughts.
If $abc = 0$, the proof is smooth. In the following, assume that $abc > 0$.
Let $x := \frac14\sqrt{24a + 1} - \frac14$,
$y := \frac14\sqrt{24b + 1} - \frac14$,
and $z := \frac14\sqrt{24c + 1} - \frac14$
(so $a = \frac23x^2 + \frac13x$, $b = \frac23y^2 + \frac13y$, and $c = \frac23z^2 + \frac13z$). Let $p = x + y + z$, $q = xy + yz + zx$, and $r = xyz$. Then
$$p, q, r > 0, \quad p^2 \ge 3q, \quad r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}. \tag{1}$$
(Note: $r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}$ is the degree three Schur inequality.) From $ab + bc + ca = a + b + c$, we have
$$-6\,{p}^{2}+2\,pq+4\,{q}^{2}-3\,p+13\,q - (8p+6)r = 0.\tag{2}$$
Also, we have $\sqrt{24a+1}+\sqrt{24b+1}+\sqrt{24c+1}- 15
= 4(x + y + z - 3) = 4(p - 3)$.
Thus, it suffices to prove that if $p, q, r$ satisfies (1) and (2), then $p \ge 3$.
This is true. Is there a nice proof of it?

Another way.
WLOG, assume that $c = \min(a, b, c)$.
From $ab + bc + ca = a + b + c$, we have
$0\le c \le 1$ and $ab \ge 1$ and $ab = (a + b)(1 - c) + c \ge (1-c)\cdot 2\sqrt{ab} + c$
which results in
$(\sqrt{ab} + c - 1)^2 \ge 1 - c + c^2$
and $\sqrt{ab} \ge 1 - c + \sqrt{1 - c + c^2}.$
By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality and AM-GM, we have
\begin{align*}
 \sqrt{24a + 1} + \sqrt{24b + 1}
 &= \sqrt{(24a + 1) + (24b + 1)
  + 2\sqrt{(24a + 1)(24b + 1)}}\\
 &\ge \sqrt{(24a + 1) + (24b + 1)
  + 2(24\sqrt{ab} + 1)}\\
 &\ge \sqrt{96\sqrt{ab} + 4}\\
 &\ge \sqrt{96 \cdot (1 - c + \sqrt{1 - c + c^2}) + 4}.
\end{align*}
It suffices to prove that, for all $0 \le c \le 1$,
$$\sqrt{96 \cdot (1 - c + \sqrt{1 - c + c^2}) + 4}
+ \sqrt{24c + 1} \ge 15. \tag{1}$$
It is easy to prove that
$1 - c + \sqrt{1 - c + c^2} \ge \frac{2}{1 + c}$.
Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt{96 \cdot \frac{2}{1+c} + 4}
+ \sqrt{24c + 1} \ge 15. \tag{2}$$
Let $x := \sqrt{24c+1} - 1 \ge 0$. We have $c = \frac{1}{24}x^2 + \frac{1}{12}x$. It suffices to prove that, for all $x \in [0, 4]$,
$$\sqrt{96 \cdot \frac{2}{1+\frac{1}{24}x^2 + \frac{1}{12}x} + 4}
+ (1 + x) \ge 15$$
which is true.
We are done.

Clean solution!!
